# Type narrowing not happening with generics

Tags: typescript, generics, types, polymorphism

Using types to restrict the possible representation of data I have, the values I consider here can be of two kinds: `Foo` or `Bar` (aliases of `string`). As far as I can tell, it means that all values I consider are of kind `Foo | Bar`.

Now, I want to write a function `equal` that takes two parameters that must be of the same type. I would like the code to fail to compile if two parameters of different types are given.

I tried to use generics, and type constraints:

```
type Foo = string;
type Bar = string;
type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

function equal<T extends FooBar>(n1: T, n2: T): boolean {
  return n1 === n2;
}

const n1: Foo = "foo";
const n2: Bar = "bar";

equal(n1, n2);
```

Sadly, this code compiles... I would like it to fail saying that `n1` and `n2` should be of the same narrow type.
I am suspecting some kind of polymorphism / type widening to be the culprit: it seems that the compiler sees them both of the wide type `FooBar`.

How can I express that `T` should be either `Foo` or `Bar`, but not `FooBar`?

Comment: `Foo` and `Bar` are exactly the same type. You just gave them a different name. But TypeScript's type system isn't *nominal*. Are you looking for [simulating nominal type aliases](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal)? If so I could write an answer or find a suitable dupe target. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Maybe I am looking to simulate that, but the proposed solution in [simulating nominal type aliases](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) assumes that I would know beforehand the string values that will be manipulated...

Comment: Hmm, no it doesn't. What makes you say that? I mean, [if I go ahead and try it with your example](https://tsplay.dev/wOK5lw) it looks reasonable to me. What, specifically, is the issue?

Comment: Nevermind, I misread the given examples. Yeah, that works, thanks :)